# Parentheses () is omitted in servlet request object

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, request

I have a request parameter that contains parentheses in a page say Page 1. Example: `param=Test(Copy)`
The flow goes from this page (page 1) to another (page 2). On click of submit in the page (page 2), the control is supposed to come back to page 1. When it comes back, it is supposed to check for this parameter, `param`. 
This is a GET request.

Now what is happening is that the value in the request parameter is `TestCopy` instead of `Test(Copy)`. Hence I get a missing resource error.

I am unable to understand what is it that could be missing.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank You!

Comment: maybe it has to do something with `urlencode`

Comment: Can show your code also

Comment: @AmitGarg: showing the code may not be possible since it is a framework level code. And it is very complicated. But we figured that the parentheses is getting encoded and while decoding it is getting truncated.

Comment: how are you calling your both url from browser/ sendRedirect?

Comment: Its working fine in my case with url http://localhost/ServletAppalication/page2Action?name=Test(Copy). I tried it using form Submit, RequestDispatcher and sendRedirect with jboss

Comment: @AmitGarg: This is a send redirect request. We are deliberately removing it as part of security concerns.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

replace ( with  %28.
 "%28" is represent "(" in request URL.
Refer following link for URL encoading
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Actually this is what we are doing. But what is happening is as part of the security, %28 is getting truncated. We have to handle that. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: can you please describe about security part? you haven't described any thing about security in question.

Comment: We have appscan check in our application. Some of the characters get removed as part of it. This I realized after checking my code in detail. So as part of the encoding ( was changed to %28 but the same was replaced by space during validation of characters. This is the reason why the parentheses were missing from the request.